# Where is "Well" needed in the Transfinite Recursion Theorem?

Tags: set-theory

The transfinite recursion theorem asserts

Let $R$ be a well-founded relation on $U$ and let $\digamma$ be a $R$-recursive rule on $U$. There is a unique function $f$ such that $\operatorname{dom}(f)=U$ and $f(x)=\digamma\left(x,f\restriction R^{-}[x]\right)$ for every $x\in U$.

I have a proof which is the standard one based on setting $f=\bigcup H$ where $h\in H$ iff $h$ is a function, and $\operatorname{dom}(h)$ is $R$-transitive in $U$, and $h(x)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}[x]\right)$ for every $x\in \operatorname{dom}(h)$.

I can't see where "wellness" comes into the proof, by which I mean I don't seem to need that $R^{-}[x]=\left\{ z\in U\mid z\mathbin Rx\right\}$ is a set for every $x$. I am using MK class theory not ZFC.

Can someone comment on the role of "wellness" in the proof in ZFC and whether it is still needed in the corresponding MK proof?

Comment: Why is $f$ a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question. I had a lot of trouble finding
a simple proof of the recursion theorem online in the form I wanted, so will
post the one I eventually have put together. I am using MK class theory although that shouldn't be too relevant. Hopefully it is all correct, please let me know if there are errors.

Let $R$ be a relation on class $U$. Recall that $R$ is **founded**
on $U$ if every $X\subseteq U\setminus\left\{ \varnothing\right\} $
has an $m\in X$ such that $X\cap R^{-}\left[m\right]=\varnothing$,
we call any such $m$ an $R$-**first member** of $X$. We say $R$ is
**well-founded** on $U$ if it is founded on $U$ and $R^{-}\left[x\right]:=\left\{ z\mid zRx\right\} $
is a set for every $x\in U$.

Given any $X\subseteq U$ we say $X$ is $R$-**inductive** on $U$ iff
for any $x\subseteq U$, if $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq X$ then
$x\in X$.

**Transfinite Induction Theorem**: *Let $R$ be a founded relation on $U$
and $X\subseteq U$. If $X$ is $R$-inductive in $U$ then $X=U$.*

Proof: Suppose for contradiction that $X\subset U$ then $U\setminus X\neq\varnothing$
and so there is an $m\in U\setminus X$ such that $x\notin R^{-}\left[m\right]$
for any $x\in U\setminus X$. If $x\in R^{-}\left[m\right]$ then
we must have $x\in X$, otherwise we would have $x\in U\setminus X$
contrary to the selection of $m$ using foundedness, so $R^{-}\left[m\right]\subseteq X$
but $X$ is $R$-inductive so $m\in X$ contrary to $m\in U\setminus X$,
absurd. Hence $X\subseteq U$ but $X\not\subset U$ so $X=U$.$\square$

We say $\digamma$ is a $R$-**recursive rule** on $U$ if it is a function
and $\left\langle x,f\right\rangle \in\text{dom}\digamma$ whenever
$x\in U$ and $f$ is a function with $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}f$.
Hence being a rule is a constraint on the domain of $\digamma$. We
require $f$ to be set so that $\left\langle x,f\right\rangle \in\text{dom}\digamma$
makes sense.

**Transfinite Recursion Theorem**: *Let $R$ be a well-founded relation
on $U$ and let $\digamma$ be a $R$-recursive rule on $U$, There
is a unique function $f$ such that $\text{dom}f=U$ and $f\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,f\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x\in U$.$\square$*

We will prove the recursion theorem by a sequence
of definitions and lemmas.

We say $T$ is $R$-**transitive** in $U$ iff $T\subseteq U$ and $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq T$
whenever $x\in T$. Clearly $U$ and $\varnothing$ are $R$-transitive
in $U$ and the $R$-transitive subclasses of $U$ are closed under
arbitrary intersections and unions.

**Lemma**: *For every $A\subseteq U$ there is a smallest $R$-transitive
class $T$ such that $A\subseteq T$.*

Proof: Set $T:=\bigcap\left\{ S\subseteq U\mid A\subseteq S\text{ and }S\text{ is }R\text{-transitive}\right\} $,
this definition works because $U$ is $R$-transitive by closure under
arbitrary intersections.$\square$

Next is the key lemma which is used several times in the following
proofs.

**Lemma**: *Suppose $g,h$ are functions whose domains are $R$-transitive
in $U$ and are such that $g\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,g\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
and $h\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x$ in their respective domains, then $g=h$ on $\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$.*

Proof: First note that for any $x\in\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$ we
have $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$ 
 by $R$-transitivity, so $g\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]$ and
$h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]$ are sets by well-foundedness
and so can participate in the domain of $\digamma$.

Let $S:=\left\{ x\in\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h\mid g\left(x\right)\neq h\left(x\right)\right\} $.
Suppose for contradiction that $S\neq\varnothing$ and let $m$ be
an $R$-first member of $S$. Since $m\in\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$
we have $R^{-}\left[m\right]\subseteq\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$
by $R$-transitivity, and for any $x\in R^{-}\left[m\right]$ we have
$g\left(x\right)=h\left(x\right)$, otherwise $x$ would contradict
$m$ being $R$-first in $S$, so we have $g\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]=h\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]$.
Hence we have $g\left(m\right)=\digamma\left(m,g\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)=\digamma\left(m,h\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)=h\left(m\right)$,
absurd, so $S=\varnothing$ and $g=h$ on $\text{dom}g\cap\text{dom}h$.
$\square$

**Lemma**: Define $f$ by $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in f$ iff there
is a function $h$ such that $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in h$,
$\text{dom}h$ is $R$-transitive in $U$, and $h\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x\in\text{dom}h$. Then $f$ is the unique function such
that $\text{dom}f=U$ and is $R$-transitive, and $f\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,f\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x\in\text{dom}f$.

Proof: For this proof call $h$ a recursor iff $h$ is a function
such that $\text{dom}h$ is $R$-transitive in $U$, and $h\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x\in\text{dom}h$. Note that if $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in f$
iff there is a recursor $h$ such that $x\in\text{dom}h$ and $h\left(x\right)=y$.
Consequently if $h$ is a recursor then $h\subseteq f$.

Since $f$ is a set of ordered pairs it is a relation.

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is not a function and let $m$
be an $R$-first member of $\text{dom}f$ at which $f$ is not single-valued.
Let $z_{1},z_{2}$ be two distinct values of $f$ at $m$ so $mfz_{1}$,
$mfz_{2}$ and $z_{1}\neq z_{2}$, so by definition there are recursors
$h_{1},h_{2}$ such that $mh_{1}z_{1}$ and $mh_{2}z_{2}$. By the
lemma we have $h_{1}=h_{2}$ on $\text{dom}h_{1}\cap\text{dom}h_{2}$
and since $m\in\text{dom}h_{1}\cap\text{dom}h_{2}$ we have $R^{-}\left[m\right]\subseteq\text{dom}h_{1}\cap\text{dom}h_{2}$
by $R$-transitivity, so $h_{1}=h_{2}$ on $R^{-}\left[m\right]$
so $z_{1}=h_{1}\left(m\right)=\digamma\left(m,h_{1}\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)=\digamma\left(m,h_{2}\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)=h_{2}\left(m\right)=z_{2}$,
absurd. Hence $f$ is a function.

If $x\in\text{dom}f$ and $z\in R^{-}\left[x\right]$, then $\left\langle x,f\left(x\right)\right\rangle \in f$
so there is a recursor $h$ such that $x\in\text{dom}h$ and $h\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$,
but $\text{dom}h$ is $R$-transitive so $z\in\text{dom}h$ and $h\left(z\right)=\digamma\left(z,h\restriction R^{-}\left[z\right]\right)$,
so by definition $\left\langle z,h\left(z\right)\right\rangle \in f$
so $z\in\text{dom}f$. Hence $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}f$
so $\text{dom}f$ is $R$-transitive.

Let $x\in\text{dom}f$ be arbitrary then $\left\langle x,f\left(x\right)\right\rangle \in f$
so for some recursor $h$ we have $x\in\text{dom}h$ and $h\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$.
Since $x\in\text{dom}h\cap\text{dom}f$ we have $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}h\cap\text{dom}f$
by $R$-transitivity and since $h\subseteq f$ we have $h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]=f\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]$
so $f\left(x\right)=h\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,h\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)=\digamma\left(x,f\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$.

Suppose for contradiction that $\text{dom}f\subset U$ and let $m$
be an $R$-first member of $U\setminus\text{dom}f$. Let $f^{+}=f\cup\left\{ \left\langle m,\digamma\left(m,f\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)\right\rangle \right\} $
then since $m\notin\text{dom}f$ we have $f\subset f^{+}$. If $x\in\text{dom}f^{+}$
then either (1) $x\in\text{dom}f$ so $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}f\subseteq\text{dom}f^{+}$
by $R$-transitivity, or (2) $x=m$ so any $z\in R^{-}\left[m\right]$
is in $\text{dom}f$ as $m$ is $R$-first, so $R^{-}\left[m\right]\subseteq\text{dom}f\subseteq\text{dom}f^{+}$,
hence in either case $R^{-}\left[x\right]\subseteq\text{dom}f^{+}$
so $\text{dom}f^{+}$ is $R$-transitive. Therefore $f^{+}$ is cleary
a recursor, $m\in\text{dom}f^{+}$ and $f^{+}\left(m\right)=\digamma\left(m,f\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)$
so $\left\langle m,\digamma\left(m,f\restriction R^{-}\left[m\right]\right)\right\rangle \in f$
so , absurd, so $\text{dom}f=U$.

Assume $g$ is also a function such that $\text{dom}g=U$ and $g\left(x\right)=\digamma\left(x,g\restriction R^{-}\left[x\right]\right)$
for every $x\in\text{dom}g$. Since $\text{dom}g=U$ it is $R$-transitive
so $g$ is a recursor so $g\subseteq f$. Suppose for contradiction
that $g\subset f$ then $\text{dom}g\subset\text{dom}f=U$, absurd.
Hence $g=f$.$\square$

Answer (score 3):

The condition for $R$ being well-founded is not that $R^-[x]$ is always a set (if that was all, every relation on a set would be well-founded), but that every non-empty subset of $U$ has an $R$-minimal element.

As an example of a relation that *doesn't* have this property, consider the usual ordering $<$ on the closed unit interval $[0,1]$. The recursion theorem would fail for this set -- for example, consider
$$ \digamma(x,h) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }[0,1]\cap\operatorname{Rng}h=\varnothing \\
\sup ([0,1]\cap \operatorname{Rng} h) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
This ought to satisfy your concept of a "$<$-recursive rule" on $[0,1]$.

However, this rule does not give rise to a *unique* $f$ -- in fact, *every continuous non-decreasing $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$* will satisfy the condition
$$ f(x)=\digamma\left(x,f\restriction R^{-}[x]\right) $$
so the recursion rule did not succeed in picking out a particular one among them.

---

The proof goes wrong in this case because $\bigcup H$ is not necessarily a *function*. In order to prove that it is, one needs the "well-founded" condition on $R$.

Comment: This correctly answers the question in the title, but I suspect the OP may actually understand the need for (what is usually called) well-foundedness, doesn't understand the need for the additional condition that $R^-[x]$ is a set, and somehow got the impression that this additional condition is called "well".

Comment: @Andreas: That's a good point. One might expect that a condition about a relation being a well means that you can actually dig deeper and deeper and still find water. Or at least toss coins and wish upon them.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. In the ZFC proof of the Transfinite Recursion Theorem is the well-founded relation required to be set-like? What about in MK?

Comment: @MarkKortink: Even if your $\digamma$ is a class function, if $R^−[x]$ is not a set, you cannot even form $\digamma\restriction R^−[x]$ and apply $\digamma$ to it. You could probably do something like that in MK by representing $\digamma$ as a formula rather than a class (so you'd get a metatheorem, like ZFC metatheormems about classes), and if you know that $\digamma(x,h)$ is always a set even when $h$ is not -- and $R$ is _extremely_ well founded (so every non-empty _subclass_ has a least element) -- you might get a complete $f$ out of it at the end.

Comment: Thanks Henning, that is the kind of guidance i was after. Regards